# Filter a model using multiple fields

Tags: python, django, filter

views.py

```
def get_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    talent = request.GET.get('talent', None)

    users = User.objects.all().order_by('last_name')

    if talent:
        user = users.filter(user_talent=talent) and users.filter(user_talent2=talent)
```

models.py

```
def get_talent(self):
    talent = f''
    if self.user_talent:
        talent = f'{self.user_talent}'
        if self.user_talent2:
            talent = f'{self.user_talent}, {self.user_talent2}'
    return talent
```

Comment: Do you want to filter where either of the fields matches or where both match?

Comment: I added a potential answer to your problem. Did it work for you or did you face any issues with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match both fields such that **both** `user_talent` and `user_talent2` is equal to `talent`:

```
qs = users.filter(user_talent=talent, user_talent2=talent)
```

If you need to match only one of the fields such that **either** `user_talent` or `user_talent2` is equal to `talent` (or can also be both):

```
from django.db import models
qs = users.filter(models.Q(user_talent=talent) | models.Q(user_talent2=talent))
```

Both calls will return another `QuerySet`. You might need to call e.g. `qs.first()` to get the first item or just change the call from `.filter()` to `.get()` if you expect it to be just 1 item.

For your reference, here are some other ways to perform the queries:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets